# How can I add React router to the content section in the main layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I am developing application using React redux-toolkit. I added the route schema, and then I get the 'wow' error saying the page can't respond when it probably goes into an infinite loop. I have a MainLayout and I want to go to the content part of it by clicking the properties of the layout in the side menu. For example, the page that gives the list of registered cities when I click, the page that gives the names of the countries. I want to give these pages in the content section of the main layout. That's why I need to give you the route diagram that I have prepared. Since I also wrap routes in the app, I think it goes into an infinite loop because it wraps the route part twice, but I don't know how I can solve it. I need help.

```
function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes><MainLayout/></PrivateRoutes>} path="/">
          {/* <Route element={<MainLayout/>} path="/"/> */}
      </Route>
      <Route element={<Login/>} path="/login"/>
      <Route element={<CityList/>} path="/city/list"/>
      <Route element={<Register/>} path="/register"/>
      <Route element={<ActivateEmail/>} path="/account/activate"/>
      <Route element={<NoMatch/>} path="*"/>
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default AppRoutes

const PrivateRoutes = ({children}) => {
  const {userToken } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
if(!userToken){
return <Navigate to="/login"/>
}else{
  return children;
}
}


export default PrivateRoutes;

function App() {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState('tr');
  return (
      <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages[locale]}>
        <AppRoutes/>
   </IntlProvider>
  );
};

export default App

import { UserOutlined, FileOutlined, SettingOutlined, DownOutlined, LogoutOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Breadcrumb, Layout, Menu, theme, Input, Space, Card, Button, Dropdown, message, Tag, Spin, Row, Col, Form } from "antd";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { RiLockPasswordLine } from 'react-icons/ri'
import {AiOutlineMenu} from 'react-icons/ai'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUserbyId, signOut } from "../utils/api.service";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getTokenSub } from '../utils/HelperFunctions';
import { getUser, userInfo } from '../types/user';
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";
import AppRouteList from "../routes/AppRouteList";
import FormButton from "../components/FormButton";
import InputDisableText from "../components/InputDisableText";
import AppRoutes, { RouteApp } from "../routes/AppRoutes";

const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;


export function MainLayout() {
    const {userToken } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const intl = useIntl();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const menuItemClick = (e) => {
        switch(e.key){
            case "menu_city_list":
                navigate("/city/list")
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    
    function getItem(label, key, icon, children) {
        return {
            key,
            icon,
            children,
            label,
        };
    }
    const items = [
        getItem("Faturalar", "sub1", <FileOutlined />, [
            getItem("Team 1", "1"),
            getItem("Team 2", "2"),
        ]),
        getItem("Sistem Ayarları", "sub2", <SettingOutlined />, [
            getItem("Ülkeler", "5"),
            getItem(intl.formatMessage({id:"menu_city_list"}),"menu_city_list",<AiOutlineMenu/>),
            getItem("Client", "7"),
            getItem("Tom", "8"),
            getItem("Bill", "9"),
            getItem("Alex", "10"),
            getItem("Tom", "11"),
            // getItem("Bill", "12"),
            // getItem("Alex", "13"),
            // getItem("Tom", "14"),
            getItem("Genel Ayarlar", "15"),
        ]),
        getItem("Hesabım", "sub3", <UserOutlined />, [
            getItem("Hesabım", "3"),
            getItem("Oturum Kapat", "4"),
        ]),
    ];
    const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
        message.info('Click on left button.');
        console.log('click left button', e);
    };
    const handleMenuClick = (e) => {
        message.info('Click on menu item.');
        console.log('click', e);
    };
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    const sub = getTokenSub(token);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    getUser.Id = sub

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUserbyId(getUser)).then((result) => {            
            userInfo.id = result.payload.id
            userInfo.clientId = result.payload.clientId
            userInfo.clientName = result.payload.clientName
            userInfo.email = result.payload.email
            userInfo.firstName = result.payload.firstName
            userInfo.lastName = result.payload.lastName
            userInfo.isActive = result.payload.isActive
            userInfo.normalizedEmail = result.payload.normalizedEmail
            userInfo.userName = result.payload.userName
            userInfo.passwordChangeTime = result.payload.passwordChangeTime
        });
    }, [dispatch, getUser])

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }, 1000);
    }, []);

    const handleLogout = () => {
        dispatch(signOut())
    };
    const itemsDropDown = [
        {
            label: 'Hesabım',
            key: '100',
            icon: <UserOutlined />,
        },
        {
            label: 'Şifremi Değiştir',
            key: '200',
            icon: <RiLockPasswordLine />,
        },
        {
            label: 'Oturum Kapat',
            key: '400',
            icon: <LogoutOutlined />,
            danger: true,
            onClick: handleLogout
        },
    ];

    const menuProps = {
        items: itemsDropDown,
        // onClick: handleMenuClick,
    };
    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
    const {
        token: { colorBgContainer },
    } = theme.useToken();
    

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
            {isLoading ? (
                <Spin size="large" />
            ) : (
                <Layout
                    style={{
                        minHeight: "100vh",
                    }}
                >
                            {console.log("user ınfo", userToken)}
                    <Sider
                        collapsible
                        collapsed={collapsed}
                        onCollapse={(value) => setCollapsed(value)}
                    >
                        <div
                            style={{
                                height: 32,
                                margin: 16,
                                background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
                            }}
                        >
                        </div>
                        <Menu
                            theme="dark"
                            defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
                            mode="inline"
                            items={items}
                            onClick={menuItemClick}
                        />
                    </Sider>
                    <Layout className="site-layout">
                        <Header
                            style={{
                                padding: 0,
                                background: colorBgContainer,
                            }}
                        >
                        </Header>
                        <Content
                            style={{
                                margin: "0 16px",
                            }}
                            >
                                {/* <AppRoutes/> PROBLEM HERE */} 

                            </div>
                        </Content>
                        <Footer
                        </Footer>
                    </Layout>
                </Layout>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I open the AppRoutes component in the comments line in the content on the main layout page, it enters an endless loop and the browser stops responding and gives an error.

[Web Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ6UJ.png)
[image: where the image should be when clicked--expectation]

[image: Appear when pressed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppRoutes` renders `MainLayout` which when rendering another `AppRoutes` renders  another `MainLayout`... do you see the problem? This creates a "render loop" by infinite recursion.

I suspect you meant for `MainLayout` to render an `Outlet` component for nested routes it may be rendering as a layout route.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

...

export function MainLayout() {
  ...

  return (
    <div style={{ .... }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Spin size="large" />
      ) : (
        <Layout style={{ .... }}>
          ...
          <Layout className="site-layout">
            <Header style={{ .... }} />
            <Content style={{ .... }}>
              <Outlet /> // <-- for nested route content
            </Content>
            <Footer />
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you are intending for `MainLayout` to be a layout route component for all routes then it should wrap all routes. The `PrivateRoute` component should also be converted to a layout route component so it can wrap all routes that should be protected.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { userToken } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  return userToken ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```

```
function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<Login />} path="/login" />
      <Route element={<Register />} path="/register" />
      {/* ... other non-main-layout routes */}
        
      <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
        <Route element={<ActivateEmail />} path="/account/activate" />
        {/* ... other unprotected routes */}

        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route element={<CityList />} path="/city/list" />
          {/* ... other protected routes */}
        </Route>

        <Route element={<NoMatch />} path="*" />
        {/* ... other main-layout routes */}
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Comment: When I still click on the link there, another page opens instead of appearing in the content, it just does not contain the layout of that component.

Comment: As you mentioned, I noticed the problem, but I still can't solve it.

Comment: @Joseph Which links are you referring to, and *what* exactly is opening not where you expect it? With the current code you aren't rendering anything in the `MainLayout`. I'm guessing at this point what you are wanting is for all the routes (*`".login"`, `"/city/list"`, etc*) to render their content in the main layout? Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @Joseph I'm going to also guess that you don't necessarily want to protect ***all*** the routes, e.g. `"/login"`, so they are reachable by unauthenticated users?

Comment: As you can see in the main layout, I have a menu and for example an element in a menu goes to /city/list when I press it. I want to show the outputs of the component of this link in the content of the main layout. So I want to update the content as the layout hard link is updated. I hope I was able to explain

Comment: login should be blocked if logged in and if there is a token

Comment: I have attached as expectation-realized image

Comment: @Joseph Based on the image it seems I'm correct in that you want all the routed content to be rendered in the content section of the main layout component. I've updated my answer. If you want to prevent authenticated users from accessing the `"/login"` route then create another protected route component that does the *inverse* of `ProtectedRoutes` and render the routes you don't want authenticated users to access inside it.

Comment: Now I get what I want, but it shows in content on login and registration pages and not as a separate page, how can I set it?

Comment: @Joseph Move those two routes out of the `MainLayout` layout route. I've updated answer again... hopefully the comments don't make it more difficult to understand how the routes and layouts are working.

Comment: I saw it later, thank you very much.